# How to get Total Number of Pages of a PDF using Ghostscript and Python

Tags: python, pdf, ghostscript

I didn't found a python compatible script to count the number of pages inside a PDF using python with Ghostscript.
I want to save the number of pages in a python variable.
Command line scripts are alrady present but i want to use it with python.
Let me know if you have found any.

Answer (score 1):

Originally, I wanted to do the same: to use `ghostscript` to count the number of pages in a pdf file. However, I came across another lib called `pypdf`, and eventually, I decided to use that instead. The following function returns the page count of the pdf available at the passed in path. I hope this helps.

```
import pypdf

def num_of_pages_for_pdf(pdf_file_path):
    """Returns the page count of the pdf available at the input path.
    
        Parameters:
            pdf_file_path (str): Local path of the pdf. E.g. '/tmp/example.pdf'
    """
    pdf_reader = pypdf.PdfReader(pdf_file_path)
    return len(pdf_reader.pages)
```

Comment: isn't there any method to count without pypdf library. i mean using ghostscript only